# How can I donate?

Tags: elementary-project

Good evening ... I like your distribution and I use it all the time, I want to donate but I do not have credit or debit cards. Is there another way to donate? ... excuse me, I am using a translator. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I donate to Elementary via Patreon: https://www.patreon.com/elementary/overview

Patreon takes PayPal as well as other payment methods.

Answer (score 2):

In the [Get Involved](https://elementary.io/es/get-involved) section you have all the ways you can donate money to elementary.

You can donate periodically using Patreon, make one donation using paypal or you can also buy something from the elementary store.

There's also another option, Bountysource. With this option you can donate money to solve a bug that's bothering you or to a elementary application that you really like :)